# How to do publisher timeouts in rabbitmq + pika

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, pika

Given that rabbitmq implements flow control, which can slow some of the message publishing down, How can one use timeouts. Also, as pika also doesnt implement publisher confirms, 
which language and library are recommended for publishing code