# How to set producer/publisher socket timeout for RabbitMQ (pika)?

Tags: rabbitmq, pika

Is there a way to make set the socket timeout when publishing?

I'm testing correct recovery from lost connection with Pika, by

- establishing a BlockingConnection connection
- disconnecting from the network to force an error
- reestablishing a connection and checking that the producer reconnects correctly and continues producing.

However, I don't seem to be able to set the socket timeout and basic_publish hangs - for WAY more than 5 seconds -- 60 or more.

```
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(worker_config.username, worker_config.password)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
    host=worker_config.host,
    credentials=credentials,
    port=worker_config.port,
    connection_attempts=1,
    retry_delay=5,
    socket_timeout=5,
))
#  No effect
#connection._impl.socket.settimeout(5)
channel = connection.channel()


while True:
   result = channel.basic_publish(
                        exchange=EXCHANGE,
                        routing_key=ROUTING_KEY,
                        body=message,
                        properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                              delivery_mode, # MQ_TRANSIENT_DELIVERY_MODE, #1
                    ))

    # Someone after some success, disconnect network.
```

Pika comes into (select_connection.py):

```
def poll(self, write_only=False):
    """Poll until the next timeout waiting for an event

    :param bool write_only: Only process write events

    """
    while True:
        try:
            events = self._poll.poll(self.get_next_deadline())
            break
        except _SELECT_ERROR as error:
            if _get_select_errno(error) == errno.EINTR:
                continue
            else:
                raise
```

... and indeed, get_next_deadline is sending 5.
_poll is a [python Poll object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#polling-objectsz) which takes a timeout in seconds.
What's up with this?

There's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248331/how-to-do-publisher-timeouts-in-rabbitmq-pika), but has no answers (not enough detail?)

Comment: I have an example on how to handle reconnects etc is for my own amqp library, but pretty sure you could do something similar with pika
https://github.com/eandersson/amqpstorm/blob/master/examples/robust_consumer.py

Comment: btw how are you testing this? disabling the network card, pulling the network cable?

Comment: Thanks -- I'm disabling the wifi on my laptop